# can not tap the calendar dates using appium, how to tap & inspect

Tags: appium, appium-desktop

Every time this view is showing in appium inspector, can't tap on the calendar dates, any remedies?[ppium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN4I1.png)

Comment: The code is working absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can tap by coordinates and get coordinates from your `AndroidElement`.

```
public void tapElementByCoordinates(AndroidElement element) {
        new TouchAction(driver).tap(PointOption.point(element.getCoordinates().onScreen().getX(),element.getCoordinates().onScreen().getY())).perform();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With below code you can  `tap` on button simply with `element`.

```
MobileElement calendarButton= (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.id(“button1”));

new TouchAction(driver).tap(tapOptions().withElement(element(calendarButton))).perform();
```